# How would you give random limits in java?

Tags: java

So let's say you want to generate a random number, but you want it to be UNDER a specified amount.
Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? So say I have int r = newColor.nextInt()... what do I do for that?

Comment: @user1150599 - He meant `r %= upperBound`, but there is a method `newColor.nextInt(upperBound)` which is equivalent.

Comment: `r = newColor.nextInt() % upperBound` is NOT equivalent to `newColor.nextInt(upperBound)`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int) for details on why the latter implementation is better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randInt = rand.nextInt( 16 ); //Generates a number in [0, 1, .., 15]
```

Documentation at: 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Comment: +1: I would use the Javadoc for Java 6 or 7 given Java 5.0 has been EOL for more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method [random.nextInt(upperBound)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided here are correct if you are looking for an integer. However, if you are not looking for an integer random number, I think the below solution would work.

If you want a random number between 50 and 100, use this:

randomNumber = 50+(Math.random()*50);